# How to parse a form with Apache Tika/Tesseract?

Tags: text, ocr, tesseract, image-recognition, apache-tika

I have a scaned 3 paged document . It has some structure to it (N fields, some are hand writen text, some are numbers). I know names of each field. How to get field values?

Comment: I think you're probably going to need to use Apache PDFBox to get all the form fields, too much information will have been lost/simplified by the time Apache Tika gives you friendly+consistent HTML back for the document